# Can't install plotKML package in R

Tags: r, plotkml

I have tried to install plotKML package, but it raises the next error. I can't see any missing dependencies and I don't know what's wrong.

```
> install.packages("plotKML")
Installing package into ‘/home/benmhamed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/plotKML_0.6-1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 3448310 bytes (3.3 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 3.3 MB

* installing *source* package ‘plotKML’ ...
** package ‘plotKML’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
** demo
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
double free or corruption (!prev)
Aborted (core dumped)
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘plotKML’
* removing ‘/home/benmhamed/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/plotKML’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘plotKML’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/Rtmpu5ujGk/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: My guess is that you're missing a linux library.

Comment: This would be a good time to [contact the maintainer](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plotKML/index.html)

Comment: @Phil at the beginning it showed a missing Linux library, but I have installed it correctly. Now I am not sure. May be I need to contact the maintainer.